# About Payment Gateway - Is it Mandatory to use only Apple Pay / iTunes pay in iOS apps

Tags: payment, gateway

Could you please give us insight on the Payment gateway integration as we have been using Stripe / Paypal  and other 3rd party sdk's in the iOS Apps and we never face any issue using them however,we have been getting a lot of queries that about if we integrate these payment gateway hence,Apple wont consider the app to be live on the Store and Apple restrict it's own Apple Pay to use in the Apps and does not let the other payment gateways to be integrated.As some apps are paid and have in app purchase so, is it true ? that on iOS platform Apple pay is only payment gateway which is allowed now to use rather than integrating other Payment gateways like Stripe / Paypal / Authorize.net

Please assist us on this. You reply is much appreciated.

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

Apple Pay is a secure way to deliver a payment instrument (like a credit card). It is totally independent of the gateway used to process it. Notes on Apple Pay usage:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201239

Supporting Apple Pay is pretty easy with a gateway like Stripe:

https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/apple-pay

The above walks through the iOS Developer process for provisioning an app. Stripe takes the encrypted Apple Pay payload and does the rest.

If your app offers some form of merchant checkout you are fully entitled to offer Apple Pay as a payment option. The Stripe iOS SDK:

https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

supports Apple Pay.